# Should a single HttpClientHandler be used with multiple HttpClient objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have multiple long-lived `HttpClient` objects connecting to different endpoints. They use the same AutomaticDecompression setting. Should I create a separate `HttpClientHandler` for each one, or is it fine to share the handler instance between them all?

```
HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

HttpClient offerClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler, true);
offerClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Content", "gzip");

HttpClient quoteClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler, true);
quoteClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Content", "gzip");

HttpClient ordersClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler, true);
ordersClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Content", "gzip");
```

Comment: Are you having a particular problem currently when sharing it? Or is this just a theoretical/speculative question?

Comment: Mostly theoretical at this point. I haven't seen any specific issues so far, but I'm unfamiliar with the under-the-hood aspects of HttpClient and want to avoid any unforeseen issues down the road.

Comment: what kinds of issues are you worried about? Speculating about potential unspecified problems is probably going to generate too broad a discussion, especially without access to the relevant source code (unless this is a part of .NET which has been open-sourced, maybe you can check).

Comment: Perhaps I should have put this in the CodeReview StackExchange then. I'm asking in order to get an idea of what potential issues there are (or are not). I couldn't find any discussion of this one way or the other.

Comment: Without access to the source code and/or some test results, any answer is likely to be largely (possibly educated) guesswork

Answer (score 3):

Conventional wisdom has it that a singleton `HttpClient` is the way to go, so sharing the same handler is certainly OK. Depending on how your DI is configured, I would be tempted to create a `GZipHttpClient` deriving from `HttpClient` and just pass the correctly-configured handler straight to the `base` ctor, and then wire that up as a singleton and request that specific Type (as opposed to `HttpClient`) via DI wherever you need this gzip stuff.